# Get information from google by node js

Tags: node.js

I've tried to write short program in node js, that will calculate the euro exchange rate compared with the dollar.
So , as everyone knows that google supply this information by search a simple sentence like:  "dollar to euro"

so, I find this code from github

```
    var google = require('google')

google.resultsPerPage = 25
var nextCounter = 0

google('node.js best practices', function (err, res){
  if (err) console.error(err)

  for (var i = 0; i < res.links.length; ++i) {
    var link = res.links[i];
    console.log(link.title + ' - ' + link.href)
    console.log(link.description + "\n")
  }

  if (nextCounter < 4) {
    nextCounter += 1
    if (res.next) res.next()
  }
})

(https://github.com/jprichardson/node-google)
this co
```

de is prints out the first 100 search results of the query node.js best practices.
But I want to access to the little sqaure of google, that holds the information that important to me.

[image: the image of the square]

And the response unfortunately didn't return this info.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this issue: https://github.com/jprichardson/node-google/issues/10

Looks like you can access the `body` and `$`(cheerio instance) to get the "box" data from the scraped response. Try finding any valid HTML selector for this box (for instance, I saw that the currency exchange number element has an html id tag of `knowledge-currency__tgt-amount` which suggests that each "box" will have its own selector)

Comment: hey, thank you for trying to help me.
Buy, in the issue you shared here, they didnt solve my issue.
Iv'e tried to find html tag or something like this by search the words in the box, but i cant find these words, they didnt exist in the body object i got back, so i think i need to request something else than the body

Comment: sorry, it just posted my comment with no purpose.
hey, thank you for trying to help me. Buy, in the issue you shared here, they didnt solve my issue. Iv'e tried to find html tag or something like this by search the words in the box, but i cant find these words, they didnt exist in the body object i got back, so i think i need to request something else than the body.